# zsh force silence on "ls --hide"

Tags: zsh

I recently switched to zsh. In bash, when I use `"ls --hide=*.pyc"` in a file with no .pyc files, ls works as expected. In zsh, "ls --hide=*.pyc" works when the directory contains .pyc files, but fails with `zsh: no matches found: --hide=*.pyc` when no matches are found.

I would like to alias ls as `"ls --hide=*.pyc"`; is it possible to get zsh to stop complaining when no matches are found?

Thank you.

Comment: You should really be escaping or quoting that asterisk. If you happened to have a directory entry like `--hide=something.pyc` (admittedly unlikely), then even `bash` would no do what you expect. Using `ls --hide=\*.pyc` or `ls --hide='*.pyc'` will work in all sane shells (since no wildcard actually is involved).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing `unsetopt nomatch`.

Answer (score 5):

Quote the filespec:

```
ls --hide="*.pyc"

alias lh='ls --hide="*.pyc"'
```